# Publish a 'flattened' WMS in ArcGIS Server

Tags: arcgis-server, wms, arcgis-10.2

we have a WMS which contains several layers, published using ArcGIS Server/WIN 10.2.  I am attempting to determine how we could 'flatten' the service to only contain 1 or 2 layers instead of several - which makes it easier for implementation into openlayers, etc - but still maintain all data.  identify capability does not need to be available, nor does the option to turn on and off layers.

Example:
[image: Current WMS config]

- 'flatten' the WMS to look like:

[image: new config - one layer only]

-or-

[image: new config, multiple layers]

Thanks Mucho

Comment: FYI the service layer numbers (1-6) do not have any significance.

Comment: Can you point, line, and polygon layers schemas be merged together to fit your WMS3 example?

Comment: I think i understand what you're asking, pardon me if not.  The points can all be combined in one layer, lines in one layer and polys in one layer - yes.  Or they could just be in one mashup layer.

Comment: Are you group layer names in your graphic representing different geographic areas?

Comment: No, however, groups are determined by scale visibility.